# StackOverflow in listview - Android

Tags: android, listview, stack-overflow

I ve got a listview with modified baseadapterr to load the pic in to the list items. When you click on the item it change the main content of the activity. Now I from time to time app crached probably because if this activity.

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
at android.widget.TextView.onDraw(TextView.java:4329)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6993)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1732)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1459)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6996)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1732)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1459)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6996)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1732)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1459)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6996)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1732)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1459)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6996)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1732)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1459)
at android.widget.AbsListView.dispatchDraw(AbsListView.java:1499)
at android.widget.ListView.dispatchDraw(ListView.java:3194)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6996)
at android.widget.AbsListView.draw(AbsListView.java:2607)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1732)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1459)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1730)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1459)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6996)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1732)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1459)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6996)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:357)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1732)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1459)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1730)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1459)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6996)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:357)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1732)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1459)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1730)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1459)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1730)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1459)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1730)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1459)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6996)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:357)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1732)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1459)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1730)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1459)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1730)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1459)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1730)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1459)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6996)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:357)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1732)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1459)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6996)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:357)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1732)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1459)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6996)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:357)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:2054)
at android.view.ViewRoot.draw(ViewRoot.java:1632)
at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1335)
at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1991)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4358)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:849)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:607)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

App test on couple phones and everything was fine in UK, but it crashed almost always in USA. Images in list items are Facebook profile pic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your activity's UI is too complicated. You have too many `ViewGroups` holding onto other `ViewGroups`. Bring your app up in an emulator and use Hierarchy View (Eclipse perspective or standalone tool) to examine the view hierarchy of this activity. You will find that from the root to the farthest leaf you have 15+ layers in the hierarchy, which is too many. Find ways to cut that back to fewer layers, such as replacing nested `LinearLayout` widgets with a single `RelativeLayout`.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it. But I wonder what is worse? Many layers in each item or main one ? I will try to get rid of LinearLayout and replace it with RelativeLayout, like you said.